# Powerquery: Expand all columns of that have records in them

Tags: powerquery

Using Power Query in Microsoft Excel 2013, I created a table that looks like this:

```
// To insert this in Power Query, append a '=' before the 'Table.FromRows'
Table.FromRows(
  {
    {"0", "Tom", "null", "null"},
    {"1", "Bob", [ name="Berlin" , street="BarStreet" ], [ name="Mary", age=25 ]},
    {"2", "Jim", [ name="Hamburg", street="FooStreet" ], [ name="Marta", age=30 ]}
  },
  {"ID", "Name", "Address", "Wife"}
)
```

Now, I want to expand the columns `Address` and `Wife` by using the `name` attribute
on both records. Manually, I would do it like this:

```
// To insert this in Power Query, append a '=' before the 'Table.FromRows'
let
  t = Table.FromRows(
    {
      {"0", "Tom", "null", "null"},
      {"1", "Bob", [ name="Berlin" , street="BarStreet" ], [ name="Mary", age=25 ]},
      {"2", "Jim", [ name="Hamburg", street="FooStreet" ], [ name="Marta", age=30 ]}
    },
    {"ID", "Name", "Address", "Wife"}
  ),
  expAddress = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(t, "Address", {"name"}, {"Address → name"}),
  expWife = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(expAddress, "Wife", {"name"}, {"Wife → name"})
in
  expWife
```

### Background

Whenever I have data tables that have a different layout, I need to rewrite the
query. In a fantasy world, you could expand all columns that have Records in
them using a specific key. **Ideally, you would have the following library
functions:**

```
// Returns a list with the names of the columns that match the secified type.
// Will also try to infer the type of a column if the table is untyped.
Table.ColumnsOfTypeInfer(
  table as table,
  listOfTypes as list
) as list

// Expands a column of records into columns with each of the values.
Table.ExpandRecordColumnByKey(
  table as table,
  columns as list,
  key as text,
) as table
```

Then, I could call

```
// To insert this in Power Query, append a '=' before the 'Table.FromRows'
let
  t = Table.FromRows(
    {
      {"0", "Tom", "null", "null"},
      {"1", "Bob", [ name="Berlin" , street="BarStreet" ], [ name="Mary", age=25 ]},
      {"2", "Jim", [ name="Hamburg", street="FooStreet" ], [ name="Marta", age=30 ]}
    },
    {"ID", "Name", "Address", "Wife"}
  ),
  recordColumns = Table.ColumnsOfTypeInfer(t, {type record}),
  expAll = Table.ExpandRecordColumnByKey(t, recordColumns, "name")
in
  expAll
```

### Question

1. Can you get a list of columns with a specific type that is not specified in the table, aka infer it?
2. Can you make that record expansion generic?

### Edit: Added row #0 with two null cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(First off, thanks for the clear explanation and sample data and suggestions!)

1) There's no way in M code to do type inference. This limitation might almost be considered a "feature", because if the source data changes in a way that causes the inferred type to be different, it will almost certainly break your query.

Once you load your untyped data, it should be quick to use the [Detect Data Type](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-latest-update/#september-2015-update-2274163351) button to generate the M for this. Or if you are reading data from JSON it should be mostly typed enough already.

If you have a specific scenario where this doesn't work want to update your question? :)

2) It's very possible and only a little convoluted to make the record expansion generic, as long as the cell values of the table are records. This finds columns where all rows are either `null` or a record and expands the `name` column.

Here's some simple implementations you can add to your library:

```
let
  t = Table.FromRows(
    {
      {"0", "Tom", null, null},
      {"1", "Bob", [ name="Berlin" , street="BarStreet" ], [ name="Mary", age=25 ]},
      {"2", "Jim", [ name="Hamburg", street="FooStreet" ], [ name="Marta", age=30 ]}
    },
    {"ID", "Name", "Address", "Wife"}
  ),

  Table.ColumnsOfAllRowType = (table as table, typ as type) as list => let
    ColumnNames = Table.ColumnNames(table),
    ColumnsOfType = List.Select(ColumnNames, (name) => 
      List.AllTrue(List.Transform(Table.Column(table, name), (cell) => Type.Is(Value.Type(cell), typ))))
  in
    ColumnsOfType,

  Table.ExpandRecordColumnByKey = (table as table, columns as list, key as text) as table  => 
    List.Accumulate(columns, table, (state, columnToExpand) => 
      Table.ExpandRecordColumn(state, columnToExpand, {key}, { columnToExpand & " → " & key })),

  recordColumns = Table.ColumnsOfAllRowType(t, type nullable record),
  expAll = Table.ExpandRecordColumnByKey(t, recordColumns, "name")
in
  expAll
```

---

If a new library function can be implemented in just M we're less likely to add it to our standard library, but if you feel it is missing feel free to suggest it at: https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi/

You might have a good argument for adding something like `Table.ReplaceTypeFromFirstRow(table as table) as table`, because constructing the type with M is very messy.

Comment: Thank you for answering. However, it is not safe to assume that the first row has records and null values can be in there. I updated my example in this regard. @Carl Walsh

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to come to this a bit late, but I just had a similar challenge.  I tried using Chris Webb's ExpandAll function:

http://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2014/05/21/expanding-all-columns-in-a-table-in-power-query/

... but that only works on Table-type columns, not Record-type columns, but I have managed to hack it to that purpose.   I duplicated Chris' function as "ExpandAllRecords" and made 3 edits: :

1. replaced `each if _ is table then Table.ColumnNames(_)` with `each if _ is record then Record.FieldNames(_)`
2. replaced `Table.ExpandTableColumn` with `Table.ExpandRecordColumn`
3. replaced `ExpandAll` with `ExpandAllRecords`

I tried getting both tables and records expanding in one function, but I kept getting type errors.

Anyway, with that in place, the final query is just:

```
let
    t = Table.FromRows(
        {
            {"1", "Tom", null, [ name="Jane", age=35 ]},
            {"2", "Bob", [ name="Berlin" , street="BarStreet" ], [ name="Mary", age=25 ]},
            {"3", "Jim", [ name="Hamburg", street="FooStreet" ], [ name="Marta", age=30 ]}
        },
        {"ID", "Name", "Address", "Wife"}
    ),
    Output = ExpandAllRecords(t)
in
    Output
```

---

### Edit:

Out of concern that that one day the great snippet (by Chris Webb, mentioned by @MikeHoney) will one day disappear), I'll mirror the entire code here:

> ```
> let
>      //Define function taking two parameters - a table and an optional column number 
>      Source = (TableToExpand as table, optional ColumnNumber as number) =>
>      let
>       //If the column number is missing, make it 0
>       ActualColumnNumber = if (ColumnNumber=null) then 0 else ColumnNumber,
>
>       //Find the column name relating to the column number
>       ColumnName = Table.ColumnNames(TableToExpand){ActualColumnNumber},
>
>       //Get a list containing all of the values in the column
>       ColumnContents = Table.Column(TableToExpand, ColumnName),
>
>       //Iterate over each value in the column and then
>       //If the value is of type table get a list of all of the columns in the table
>       //Then get a distinct list of all of these column names
>       ColumnsToExpand = List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(ColumnContents, 
>                          each if _ is table then Table.ColumnNames(_) else {}))),
>
>       //Append the original column name to the front of each of these column names
>       NewColumnNames = List.Transform(ColumnsToExpand, each ColumnName & "." & _),
>
>       //Is there anything to expand in this column?
>       CanExpandCurrentColumn = List.Count(ColumnsToExpand)>0,
>
>       //If this column can be expanded, then expand it
>       ExpandedTable = if CanExpandCurrentColumn 
>                           then 
>                           Table.ExpandTableColumn(TableToExpand, ColumnName, 
>                                  ColumnsToExpand, NewColumnNames) 
>                           else 
>                           TableToExpand,
>       //If the column has been expanded then keep the column number the same, otherwise add one to it
>       NextColumnNumber = if CanExpandCurrentColumn then ActualColumnNumber else ActualColumnNumber+1,
>
>       //If the column number is now greater than the number of columns in the table
>       //Then return the table as it is
>       //Else call the ExpandAll function recursively with the expanded table
>       OutputTable = if NextColumnNumber>(Table.ColumnCount(ExpandedTable)-1) 
>                          then 
>                          ExpandedTable 
>                          else 
>                          ExpandAll(ExpandedTable, NextColumnNumber)
>      in
>      OutputTable
> in
>      Source
> ```
>
> You can then use this function on the XML file as follows:
>
> ```
> let
>      //Load XML file
>      Source = Xml.Tables(File.Contents("C:\Users\Chris\Documents\PQ XML Expand All Demo.xml")),
>      ChangedType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"companyname", type text}}),
>
>      //Call the ExpandAll function to expand all columns
>      Output = ExpandAll(ChangedType)
> in
>      Output
> ```
>
> <sub>(**Source** and downloadable example: **[Chris Webb's Bi Blog, 2014-05-21](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2014/05/21/expanding-all-columns-in-a-table-in-power-query/)**)</sub>

Comment: Gist for Chris Webb's function to expand table-type columns: https://gist.github.com/Mike-Honey/f5f3f708310eb1de7f4a

Comment: Gist for my tweak to expand record-type columns: https://gist.github.com/Mike-Honey/0a252edf66c3c486b69b