# Expand Records dynamically

Tags: powerquery, m

I want to dynamically expand records because the entrys i get are not fixed.

This is working but it's fixed and i have to say which elements should be expanded.

```
let
        Quelle = Sage.Contents(),
        records = Quelle{[Name="Kontakte"]}[Data],
        #"SelectItems" = Table.SelectColumns(records,{"$items"}),
        #"$items1" = #"SelectItems"{0}[#"$items"],
        #"ToTable" = Table.FromList(#"$items1", Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
        #"ExpandedColumn" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"ToTable", "Column1", {"id", "displayed_as", "$path"}, {"Column1.id", "Column1.displayed_as", "Column1.$path"})
    in
        #"ExpandedColumn"
```

Webservice Response:

```
{
"$total":3,"$page":1,"$next":null,"$back":null,"$itemsPerPage":20,
"$items":[
{"id":"1","displayed_as":"Test","$path":"/contacts/Test"},
{"id":"2","displayed_as":"Test2","$path":"/contacts/Test2"},
{"id":"3","displayed_as":"Test3","$path":"/contacts/Test3"}
]}
```

"$items" are dynamically. It depends on how much informations are behind the contacts.

```
"id", "displayed_as", "$path"
```

could also be

```
"id", "displayed_as", "$path", "city", "zip", "street", "number"
```

or

```
"id", "displayed_as", "$path", "city", "zip", "street", "number", "phone", "mobile"
```

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35767600/powerquery-expand-all-columns-of-that-have-records-in-them

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add two variables and edit the expand line:

```
SelectAllColumns = Table.ColumnNames(#"$items1"), //Create a list with the columns names
SelectAllColumns2 = List.Transform(SelectAllColumns, each "a."&_), //Create a second list with columns names changed like a.columnname
#"ExpandedColumn" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"ToTable", "Column1", SelectAllColumns, SelectAllColumns2) //Replace these lists inside your last line
```

I think the final result will be something like:

```
let
    Quelle = Sage.Contents(),
    records = Quelle{[Name="Kontakte"]}[Data],
    #"SelectItems" = Table.SelectColumns(records,{"$items"}),
    #"$items1" = #"SelectItems"{0}[#"$items"],

    SelectAllColumns = Table.ColumnNames(#"$items1"),
    SelectAllColumns2 = List.Transform(SelectAllColumns, each "a."&_),

    #"ToTable" = Table.FromList(#"$items1", Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"ExpandedColumn" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"ToTable", "Column1", SelectAllColumns, SelectAllColumns2)
in
    #"ExpandedColumn"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the previous step in M was named `Removed Other Columns`, and that the column to expand is named `Data`, then I replace the static line of `#"Expanded Data"` with the following code:

```
#"Expanded Data" =Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Data", List.Union(List.Transform(#"Removed Other Columns"[Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))))
```

It dynamically adapt to any column names.